# Using SQL Script, create a text file with new line character

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a text file that includes line breaks. I have this code:

```
DECLARE @Text AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Cmd AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @Text = 'This is my text line 1 (supposed to be new line character) This is line2'
SET @Cmd ='echo ' + @Text + ' > C:\FileStore\test.txt'

EXECUTE Master.dbo.xp_CmdShell  @Cmd, NO_OUTPUT
```

What should i use to have a new line character on the text file so that the output should be

```
This is my text line 1
This is line2
```

**UPDATE:**
I've tried this as per suggestions

```
SET @Text = 'This is my text line 1' + char(13) + char(10)+ 'This is line2'
```

But with this, it won't create the txt file anymore

Thanks

Comment: Tag dbms used, that code is far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the syntax used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses a *carriage-return line-feed* sequence to indicate a new line, character codes 13 & 10 so:

```
select 'hello' + char(13) + char(10) + 'world'
```

<sup>(Note than in SSMS grid view you will just see a double space)</sup>

> it won't create the txt file any more

Ah thats the `echo` command line not supporting new-lines.

You could

```
echo This is my text line 1 > "C:\FileStore\test.txt" & echo This is line2 >> "C:\FileStore\test.txt"
```

Or find a different way that does not involve the command line.

Comment: hi thanks for the response, when i try this, it won't create the txt file any more.

Answer (score 3):

Use CHAR(13) to output a carriage return, or CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) for carriage return plus line feed (for windows)

Comment: thanks for the response, i've tried as you suggested, however when i run the script, it won't create the txt file

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;
GO
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  


DECLARE @cmd varchar(8000), @var varchar(2000)
SET @cmd =  'echo line1 > "d:\test.txt"' 
+           '& echo line2 >> "d:\test.txt"' 
+           '& echo line3 >> "d:\test.txt"' 
+           '& echo line4 >> "d:\test.txt"' 
+           '& echo line5 >> "d:\test.txt"' 

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd; 


EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;
GO
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Comment: Usually is expected to explain your answer a little, not only posting code with some comments.